# fetch() doing GET instead of POST on react-native (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch

I have the following code in my component:

```
fetch('https://domain.com/api', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    key: 'value'
  })
}).
  then((response) => {
    console.log('Done', response);
  });
```

And every time the request is a GET (checked server logs). I thought it was something to do with `CORS` (but apparently no such thing in `react-native`) and ATS (but already turned off by default, plus my domain is HTTPS). I've tried from a browser and from a `curl` and it worked perfectly, so a priori no issue on server configuration. Any idea what's going on here?

I'm using the latest `react-native` version.

Comment: hmm, have you done some tests using GET instead of POST? maybe the code in the phone is not updated yet with 'post'

Comment: for me it works with `'post'` , in lowercase

Comment: GET works of course but it's a creation of resource, so POST is what I need. And I tried lowercase too, nothing works. I didn't mention it but I'm experiencing this issue on the simulator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After further digging, it was definitely an issue with the API + `fetch`. I was missing a slash at the end of the URL and the API issued a 301, that `fetch` didn't handle correctly. So I don't know if there is something to fix in the fetch function (and underlying mechanisms) but this fixed my issue :)

Comment: This was happening to me as well, however what was really weird is that it was only happening in a "release" build of my app deployed to a physical phone.  Debug builds would POST correctly every time.  Adding a trailing "/" to the route fixed the issue for me.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

When a POST is redirected (in my case from http to https) it gets transformed into a GET. (Don't know why...)