# React Hook Form not posting request correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and im trying to develop a simple CRUD application, however I cant seem to figure out why my form isnt posting correctly? It isnt a problem with my backend endpoint as I've tried manually posting HTTP requests. I think its an issue with my form as it defaults to the "GET" method and shows the field values in the address bar after submission. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Avatar, Button, CssBaseline, TextField, Link, Grid, Box, Typography, Container } from '@material-ui/core/';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));



export default function Signup() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
      history.push('/profile');
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);


  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const payload = {
      username:firstName + " " + lastName,
      email: email,
      password1: password,
      password2: confirmPassword,
    };

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.key) {
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.key);
        history.push('/profile');
      } else {
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        setConfirmPassword('');
        localStorage.clear();
        setErrors(true);
      }
    });
  };



  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        
          <Typography component="h2" variant="h4" >
            Sign Up
          </Typography>
        
        <form className={classes.form} id = "signup" method = "POST" onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required ={true}
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                value = {firstName}
                onBlur={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
                onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                name="lastName"
                autoComplete="lname"
                value = {lastName}
                onBlur={e => setLastName(e.target.value)} 
                onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)} 
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                value = {email}
                onBlur={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="none"
                value = {password}
                onBlur={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} 
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} 
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Confirm Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="none"
                value = {confirmPassword}
                onBlur={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)} 
                onChange={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)} 
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            form = "signup"
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/login" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Login
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901149/fetch-doing-get-instead-of-post-on-react-native-ios

Comment: Do you have any errors in console before or just after submit? Toggle `Preserve log` option in javascript developers console for errors do not clear on reload.

Comment: Have you checked out react-hook-form? It makes all things form related much easier (and with fewer re-renders than using `useState` hooks for each input)
 https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: @Barryman9000 Oh I have not heard of react-hook-form, I'll shall give it a shot!